# Naive Bayes for GPA classification?

Tags: r, classification, regression

As a beginner in machine learning, I am faced with a project where I have to find a method that uses both categorical and numerical variables collected from surveys to predict a child's "discretized" GPA values.

For example, the x-variables include yes/no/don't know responses to questions such as "I worry about taking tests", and numerical answers such as household income. The surveys were given to teachers, caregivers, and the children themselves.

The y-variable, is GPA and ranges from 1 to 4 in discrete increments of 0.25.

What I have attempted, is to use `boruta` package to pick out the most relevant 65 features out of over 10000 features (and all of the features do make sense---they are often related to the child's behavior in school, and/or the child's scores/percentiles on standardized tests). Below is a sample of the features selected by `boruta`.

```
A3D. Your dad misses events or activities that are important to you
G2C. I worry about taking tests
G2D. It's hard for me to pay attention
G2H. It's hard for me to finish my schoolwork
G2I. I worry about doing well in school
G2M. I get in trouble for talking and disturbing others
G19A. Frequency you had 4 or more drinks in one day in past 12 months
E6A. Father could count on someone to co-sign for a bank loan for $5000
i13. how much you earn in that job, before taxes
I19A. Amount earned from all regular jobs in past 12 months
J1. Total household income before taxes/deductions in past 12 months
J4A. Name on bank account
J6B. Amount owed on your vehicle
```

Then I ran a naive Bayes classifier. I do not know if this is appropriate or if there are better methods for this task, but the results are simply terrible. The model often produces extreme values such as 1 and 4, when the actual value should be somewhere in between. I thought I had relevant features for the task, but somehow the accuracy is very low.

I have also tried gradient boosting machine from `caret` package using the default parameters, but the result isn't very satisfying either.

What can I do to improve the model, and is there better methods to try?

Is regression more suited for this if I want to achieve better accuracy/minimize error?

Thanks!

Comment: This question might be better suited to Cross Validated forum.